# Chromebook Fullscreen KeyCode?

Tags: javascript, keycode

On particular Chromebook keyboards, there are no `F1` through `F12` keys. In such cases, there are other keys in place that include "Go Back," "Refresh," "Full Screen," etc, keys instead. Search "chromebook keyboard" and look under images for more detail.

For traditional keyboards, full screen is `F11`, but for the Chromebook keyboard, it is the `Full Screen` key. I have code surrounding the `F11` key and I would like to account for the Chromebook `Full Screen` key but I do not know the keyCode and, unfortunately, [keycode.info](https://keycode.info) and some other sites do not recognize the key.

Is there a keyCode for the chromebook `Full Screen` key? Or is there some other way to access it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/177891?hl=en states that it should be synonymous with F4.

Comment: Google has a great article https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/keyboardevent-keys-codes, and a link in there to a pretty comprehensive key event displayer: https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html

Comment: Thank you for your responses! 

@RyanSchaefer, for the link, I believe the `F4` mentioned would still be synonymous with the Chromebook `Full Screen`. If it were the same as `F4`, on any keyboard, I believe there could be many collisions with other shortcuts. Furthermore, I attempted to implement this but it didn't work. 

@Snowmonkey, I looked into the first link and it seemed to only talk about accessing keys by their physical button vs. character output. For the key displayer, the `Full Screen` Chromebook key unfortunately did not show up.

Thanks again and sorry for the late reply!